# Improving the Light spell... with lanterns?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

The [*light*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/light) spell provides a 20-foot radius of bright light and 20 additional feet of dim light.

But a [hooded lantern](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/lantern-hooded) provides 30 feet of bright and 30 more feet of dim light (and a [Bullseye Lantern](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/lantern-bullseye) provides a 60-foot cone of bright light and dim light for an additional 60 feet).

Any reason you couldn't cast *light* on a small object and pop it into one of these items to get the same performance?

I tend to think "yes" because this is as simple as the difference between a naked bulb, and a bulb with a specific arrangement of reflectors around it.

Plus the *light* spell casts light in **all** directions, the hooded lantern reflects light in a plane and the bullseye lantern in a narrow cone. It's not like this isn't basically covered by the laws of physics.

I can even imagine specially built lanterns with an arrangement to make it easier to cast *light* on a copper piece and then drop the copper into a specially built slot.

But I'm fine with the *light* spell being cast on "the lantern's wick" - And even if you think *light* lights up the whole object (see similar questions) there's no reason the copper piece trick wouldn't work (or pulling the wick, casting *light* on that, etc.)

Am I missing something? Or does this open up the D&D world for a special type of lantern designed for the *light* spell?

**I think this question boils down to - Can one use existing D&D world 'technology' in combination with magic?**

The existing technology is "Reflectors work well to channel light sources" - So what's wrong with combining common knowledge with a magical light source?

On the other end of the spectrum, if the question was "Can I build an electromagnet and power it with a lightning bolt?" the answer would be *"Hells no! Nobody in the D&D world knows what an electromagnet is!"*

Comment: ...What is your actual question?

Comment: Also, another very related question asked by you: [Can I use a Light spell instead of oil in a Lantern of Revealing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127494/can-i-use-a-light-spell-instead-of-oil-in-a-lantern-of-revealing) (As written, this question seems sort of like a duplicate, except this question seems more like a discussion prompt - which would be inappropriate for a Q&A site like RPG.SE.)

Comment: The original question was in two parts. Then someone edited it down to one and suggested I ask this separately.

So here I am, asking again.

Comment: "Can one use existing D&D world 'technology' in combination with magic?" - this question is still too broad. What I think you're actually trying to ask is, "If I cast Light on the wick of a lantern (or on another object placed inside the lantern), would it provide the same lighting as the lantern normally would?" Is that correct?

Comment: Way too specific. Plus I'm happy with the answer I got before you put this on hold as they offered sensible, general guidance around (what I thought was) a sensible, general question.

Comment: Relevant FAQ from meta: [Why was my question closed as too broad, unclear, or opinion-based?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/why-was-my-question-closed-as-too-broad-unclear-or-opinion-based)

Comment: Fair comment and fair to close it.

Short of a list of questions about *every spell* and *every piece of technology* this is unanswerable in a RAW context.

Plus I'm happy with the general guidelines provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any reason you couldn't cast light on a small object and pop it into one of these items to get the same performance?
>
> I tend to think "yes" because this is as simple as the difference between a naked bulb, and a bulb with a specific arrangement of reflectors around it.

The interaction between magical effects and logic based on real-world physics is a murky area that *in general* could get you into trouble.

If:

- It makes sense to you and others playing with you
- It does not cause odd rulings or balance issues elsewhere in the game
- It does not waste time on arguments around the table

then all is good.

In this case, the PC carrying the lantern is paying the full cost of both obtaining the object and needing a free hand to use it effectively. Notably, in combat, a lantern is not as convenient to the bearer as a e.g. a Light spell cast on a helm or shield. So the balance is mainly using a spell versus cost and weight of fuel. In a game where fuel use and/or weight is not strictly tracked (which is a common simplification at many tables), then the difference is almost nothing.

However, there are good arguments that is not RAW use of the spell (because the spell does what it says it does), so if you have people in your group that like to play strictly by the rules, it is probably not worth pushing the idea too hard.

Comment: Magic isn't science. I've always found that doing anything other than doing exactly what the spell says is a very, very slippery slope. Don't do science, kids, its how you lose friends.

Comment: Good point - I added a specific question and counter-example for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines. This will be good for both allowing and disallowing items.

Ex. If someone wants a light spell powered, mag-light equivalent mounted on their crossbow the answer will be no. 

Because while a lantern is an existing tech in 5e, the flashlight (let alone the tactical flashlight mount) is not.

Comment: @SumofeDpi while a flashlight (hand-held directional light tube) is not medieval tech, the bullseye lantern and the lighthouse (one of which appears in the basic rules, the other in official adventures) use a similar principle of selectively placed shades, reflectors, or lenses to guide and focus light in particular directions. So I would tend to allow this to replace an actual flame in existing lantern designs, but not to invent a tubular flashlight that you clip onto a weapon or hold in your hand. And hanging a bullseye lantern off a crossbow could throw off your aim.